# FileProvider - permissions

Tags: android

I am curious about lifecycle of permission when using android.support.v4.content.FileProvider. Documentation for [FileProvider](http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) says:

> Set the android:grantUriPermissions attribute to true, to allow you to grant temporary access to files.

And

> Permissions granted in an Intent remain in effect while the stack of the receiving Activity is active. When the stack finishes, the permissions are automatically removed. Permissions granted to one Activity in a client app are automatically extended to other components of that app.

But on the other side, documentation for [providers](http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html#exported) says:

> If you enable this feature, either by setting this attribute to "true" or by defining  subelements, you must call Context.revokeUriPermission() when a covered URI is deleted from the provider.

Question is: What is "stack of receiving Activity"? Is is Back-stack(History)? If no, then when should I revoke permission (or at which time system will care about that)?

Comment: stack  is back stack.You need to revoke permisson when you delete a covered Uri in the provideer.

Answer (score 0):

As I see this - stack it's a stack of activities inside application, which one use your file. It could be external activities, in case if you open file by 3rd party app, or your own activity, doesn't matter. You should revoke permissions as soon, as you don't need this file to be shared anymore.